# The xpath expression '/html' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, xpath, jenkins, capybara

I know that error has been raised in other q's, but there were no helpfull answers.

I am using Capybara, Turnip and Selenium with IEDriver, browser - IE8, runnin tests on Jenkins CI
Protected Mode - off, all security levels - low

My capabilities

From CI log

```
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:18573/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=false, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

From my code

```
when 'selenium-ie-remote'
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.timeout = ENV['CLIENT_TIMEOUT'] ? ENV['CLIENT_TIMEOUT'].to_i  :  60
    capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new
    capabilities[:introduce_flakiness_by_ignoring_security_domains] = true
    capabilities[:javascript_enabled] = true
    capabilities[:css_selectors_enabled] = true
    capabilities[:ignore_protected_mode_settings] = true
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
      :browser => :remote,
      :url => "http://#{ENV['VM']}:4444/wd/hub",
      :http_client => client,
      :desired_capabilities => :internet_explorer,
      :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
    end
```

Error raises in step

```
step 'I should see :text' do |variable|
    wait_until_true { page.should have_content variable }
end

def wait_until_true(wait_time_seconds = Capybara.default_wait_time)
    start_time = Time.now
    loop do
        return true if yield
        break unless Time.now - start_time <= wait_time_seconds
        sleep(0.05)
    end
end
```

Error appears even without method `wait_until_true` so it is not the reason it fails.

Also, that error appears from time to time (1 time in 5 re-runs), so it is not consistent.

In addition, I noticed that error appear when app is redirecting to another page by itself (ex. click Save button - index page appears)

Does anybody know solution for that?

Comment: So what stage as you using the xpath `/html` and is there any particular reason you're using it?

Comment: @MarkRowlands I am not using that xpath - I think driver identifying 'page' as /html...

Comment: Ah I see, that's an issue I haven't come across before. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One decision for me is to wait Capybara wait-time

```
def found_this_element(text)
  start_time = Time.now
  begin
    page.should have_content text
  rescue => e
    throw e if Time.now - start_time >= Capybara.default_wait_time
    retry
  end
end
```

But it is workaround, how to change settings for IE that help to omit an error...